# JAVA | Error "The array is only written, never read from"

Tags: java

Error al declarar y pasar 2 array a un método. Devuelve error: "The array is only written, never read from"

```
public class CombinadorArray {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int[] a = {8, 8, 8, 8, 8};
        int[] b = {2, 2, 2};
        combinarArray(a,b);
    }
    public static int[] combinarArray(int a[], int b[]){
        int[] combinado;
        //aquí hará una serie de cosas
        return combinado;
    }
}
```

Comment: creo que se refiere a que estás ignorando el resultado de `combinarArray`. Te recomiendo cambiarle su tipo de retorno a void

Comment: puedes decir en que línea marca el ide ese problema?

Comment: Línea 3 y 4 marcan ese error.

Answer (score 2):

No puedes retornar variables sin inicializar es por esta razon que no puedes compilar el codigo, si necesitas regresar un arreglo vacio hay que declararlo explicitamente, si por el momento no necesitas retonar nada mejor seria usar **void** y evitar esos incovenientes.

```
public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int[] a = {8, 8, 8, 8, 8};
        int[] b = {2, 2, 2};
        combinarArray(a,b);
    }
    public static int[] combinarArray(int a[], int b[]){
        int[] combinado ={}; // int[] combinado = new int [0]; //tambien seria valido
        //aquí hará una serie de cosas
        return combinado;
    }

}
```